# How to get a traffic from a remote address?

Tags: c#, php, google-analytics, traffic

I was searching all over the internet and I still can't really understand how pages like www.trafficestimate.com works.

Is there an easy way to get traffic information of any web page? I assume I need to use some kind of analytics API but still not sure. Google Analytics seems to provide GAPI API for getting info from your own page only.

I wrote a script with cURL that gets traffic info from pages like trafficestimate.com, etc. But sometimes I need to get traffic info from like 4-5k of webpages and they start blocking me. :-)

Can someone help me with this? I don't really care about the programming language or platform I would need to use.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know trafficestimate specifically, but I know similar services that have toolbars installed in the browsers of a population sample - they offer small perks or a little money if you let them record your traffic and search keywords. Based on the data from that sample they do statistical calculations to guesstimate the total numbers.

I have compared numbers for clients that I track via GA with the numbers from such a service and traffic numbers where off by some 300%. So I'm not convinced this approach works particularly well, and I would put even less trust in www.trafficestimate.com as they do not disclose how they arrive at their numbers.

There is no feasible/legal way to get at the traffic numbers of sites that belong to other people (after all this is sensitive and closely guarded company information; for many online properties the visitors base determines the value of the company).

Comment: Thank you for the info. It seems to be more complicated than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the example of Alexa. They rank traffic by using a toolbar. The toolbar tracks the activity of it's users and reports back to Alexa servers. Alexa uses this data to rank traffic. Google might be able to report searches and clicks as well as tracking through it's toolbar and whatever spying it might do through the chrome browser. The key is to have access to data from a multitude of users.

Comment: Thank you. I understand more and more about this now and I don't like it. I was hoping it to be easy. :-)